# Difference between toString() method and using (+"")

Tags: java

If I have almost any kind of data type (that I can remember), I can do the following:

1. `int x = 5;`

   Call function with definition

   ```
   function_name(String x){
       //do something
   }
   ```

   like this **function_name(x+"")**//can use (+"") to almost any kind that I can remember
2. And sometimes use `.toString()` to some data types or even classes.

I do understand meaning of both. But I am really confused to one thing.

**My question:**
Why do we bother to make `toString()` method to any class even if it works fine using `(+"")`?
Is it just a way to provide users of our class to use this `toString()` method or is it faster? **Are they alternatives?**

Hope I clearify my question. Thank you.

Comment: @EJP OMG, what is that then?

Comment: right question should be difference between `toString()` and `(String)` casting

Comment: @Nabin (String)x is casting. +"" invokes a compiler-defined overload of the + operator. Nothing to do with casting whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `myObject + ""` is equivilant to calling `myObject.toString() + ""`, so the `+ ""` is just redundant.

**Question:** and what about doing it to integer? isn't it casting?

**Answer:** It's an implicit call to String.valueOf()

Comment: We can do just +"" even without toString() method in somecases. Can you tell me why to make toString() method? That is my question, not how it works. Is it about speed or something else?

Comment: That was my point - it will implicitly call a conversion to string

Comment: and what about doing it to integer? isn't it casting?

Comment: It's an implicit call to String.valueOf()

Comment: @Nabin-Integers are specific cases for that. But,you can consider other cases like User-defined Classes. Try to print the value of that object and you'll come across `hashcode`. hence,`toString()` is overridden and `+""` is just for primitive data-types!

Comment: @Nabin It calls String.valueOf(int) in that case. The special-casing occurs as a result of the overloading of String.valueOf().

Comment: myObject+"" will not throw NPE when myObject is null,but myObject.toString()+"" will.

Comment: @Mureinik There are alot of useful answers in comment here, I think you should edit your answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

- When you do `+""` on an object you are really calling the `toString()` method.
- If you do `+""` on an object that hasn't overwritten `toString()` then the `toString()` method of the `Object` class is called. Producing something like `MyClass@1948cc8c`. That way you know that `+""` is of no use without `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
toString()
```

Is a method declared in class Object which all classes implicitly inherit from. The toString() method there returns the classname followed by @ followed by the hashCode() in a hex string by default.

The Integer class, and many other classes, override this method to provide something useful.

List class does not do this. If you try to

```
System.out.println(myList + "");
```

You'll get such an odd looking string. Try it. It is not the "address" of anything like many others suggest.

So in short, if variable+"" works for you, .toString() is already implemented. Explicitly calling .toString() changes nothing, it's what happens anyway. If it doesn't work with var+"" it doesn't work any better with .toString(). You can solve both by implementing (overriding) the .toString() method of the class.

Answer (score 1):

they are almost the same except one difference:
`myObject+""` will not throw NPE when myObject is null,but `myObject.toString()+""` will.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `myObject + ""` is equivalent to calling `String.valueOf(myObject) + ""`. String.valueOf() in turn is overloaded to do various things dependent on the argument type, including returning "null" for null object arguments, calling argument.toString() for non-null object arguments, or for example Integer.toString(int) for integer arguments.

So your question doesn't make sense. As +"" results in calling toString(), it isn't an alternative to it.

Comment: I got it. I meant that was my question at first.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference i see with this approach ""+x is that no of intermediate objects can be more compare to just using toString.

However this might not be always true because the jvm might perform some optimisation to avoid creation of multiple objects.Refer text in bold below:

From [jls-15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

> The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object
>   that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters
>   of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand
>   operand in the newly created string.
>
> The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a
>   compile-time constant expression (§15.28).
>
> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation
>   in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate
>   String object. **To increase the performance of repeated string
>   concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a
>   similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects
>   that are created by evaluation of an expression.**
>
> For primitive types, an implementation may also optimize away the
>   creation of a wrapper object by converting directly from a primitive
>   type to a string.

Just for info,this is how it works for primitive types,from [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> Any type may be converted to type String by string conversion. A value
>   x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value as if by
>   giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance creation
>   expression (§15.9): If T is boolean, then use new Boolean(x). If T is
>   char, then use new Character(x). If T is byte, short, or int, then use
>   new Integer(x). If T is long, then use new Long(x). If T is float,
>   then use new Float(x). If T is double, then use new Double(x). This
>   reference value is then converted to type String by string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

toString() may not always print what you want. If you use it on objects* that have not been overridden, it'll print the address of the object. You can overwrite toString() to behave as you need.

Comment: But my question is away from your answer though it's correct

Comment: It will return whatever the toString() method decides, which varies with the class if the object.

Comment: ya clearly this is not the answer i was expecting. I already mentioned it in question that I knew about .

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid toString (), as that is how java gets the string representation of an object.  x+"" calls x.toString().

Comment: Actually it calls String.valueOf(), which calls toString() for object types.